# Apply filter on sql query conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a parameter `@Name` in a Stored Procedure. I want to filter by this parameter **only** if it is not empty / null. In any other case I want to ignore the filter.

I came up with the following two solutions. For the sake of example let us consider only the case that parameter is empty.

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where (len(rtrim(ltrim(@Name))) > 0 and Name = @Name) or (len(rtrim(ltrim(@Name))) = 0)
```

and the second one

```
@query = 'select * from MyTable'
if (len(rtrim(ltrim(@Name))) > 0)
    @query = @query + ' Name = @Name '
```

Both of the approaches are working as expected.

- Which do you think is the most clean (in terms of code) and easily maintainable
- Are there any other (better) alternatives.

Note: This question may also suit in Code Review, please comment if you think so, in order to migrate there

Comment: `or @Name is null`?

Comment: @jarlh I just omitted it, to keep the example cleaner

Comment: @Athafoud : Please look my answer . It shows you how you can extend you query and maintain it better in case when stroed proc become very lengthy . I use diffrent table name for eaxple you can change as per you needs and it works really well .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be simplified like this

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where  Name = @Name or @Name = '' or @Name is null
```

or as mentioned in comments, use `NULLIF` to check for empty string then replace it with `NULL` then validate it against `IS NULL`

```
where (Name = @Name or nullif(@Name, '') is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for length, by default, sql server is trailing-spaces-sensitive (The only exception to this rule is when the right side of the LIKE predicate's expression contains trailing spaces, then the pad is not removed).

Take the code below.

```
DECLARE @Name='              '

IF(@Name='') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

If you run the above code above you will get a result of 1. In your case, you can drop the LTRIM and RTRIM and simply test for equality against an empty string literal.

```
select *
  from MyTable
  where ((@Name='' OR @Name IS NULL)OR(Name = @Name))
```

OR

```
IF(@Name='') SET @Name=NULL

select *
      from MyTable
      where (@Name IS NULL OR Name = @Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with dynamic sql in stored procedure try something like this . It is better to use different variables for main select query and dynamic where query which can be extended easily . using this approach it will be easy to maintain when you proc becomes lengthy.

```
    declare @finalquery varchar(max)
    declare @mainSelectquery nvarchar(500);
    declare @whereCondtions varchar (1000);
    declare @DateParam datetime
    set @mainSelectquery=''
    set @whereCondtions =''

    set @finalquery =''

    set @DateParam=getdate()
    set @mainSelectquery = 'select * from tblOrders  where 1=1  '

    set @whereCondtions =  ' and Order_site =''TSN'''

    set @whereCondtions = @whereCondtions + ' AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)' 

    set @finalquery =( @mainSelectquery + @whereCondtions)

    print @finalquery

 ---- You can further extend this by adding more where condition based on the parameter pass in stored proc 
 if (@OrderID !=0)
 begin 
 set @whereCondtions =  ' OrderID='+str ( @stateRefID )
 end
```